# HTML - 'Persistance Navbar'?

Tags: html, navbar

I was wondering if it was possible to do the following in HTML.

**index.html:**

```
<title>Awesome Website</title>
<link href="navbar.html" rel="i-dunno-what-to-put-here" type="text/html"/>
<p>Content</p>
```

**navbar.html:**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.html">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.html">4</a></li>
</div>
```

So pretty much - all pages link to the navbar.html and if there is one change in the navbar, then **all** the pages change.

Does anyone know if this is possible / how to do it?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use a server side language to include that page, or use an iframe.

Comment: I'd go with the server side language option, check the [**PHP include function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for example.

Comment: if you are using jquery, you can try with '.load()' function. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Davor Mlinaric, nice and fast solution but with only one drawback, if the client has JavaScript disabled then this won't work unless he makes a back-up way like an iframe which he hides with JQuery.

Comment: @JEES ... true, but if user have javascript disabled then 90% of webpages will not work properly for him... best solution is server side, like you suggested but only if he use php or asp, or using some template engine.

Comment: @Davor Mlinaric I agree.

Comment: I've been trying to use jquery, I thought almost no-one has javascript disabled in this day and age.

I've done:

   '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>'
   '<script>'
       '$('#navbar').load('./navbar.html');'
   '</script>'



but nothing happens. :( Anyone know how to get it to work?

(and yes, I am kinda a noob)

Comment: sorry if its hard to read - I can't get it to leave a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used PHP include like JEES mentioned.