# jQuery.load to load HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, web, navbar

I've **never** used [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) before this, but I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Awesome Website</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<!--    <iframe width="100%" height="175" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="navbar.html"></iframe> I used to use this - but i cant have dropdown menus. -->
            <!-- This is my problem -->
        <script>
                $('#navbar').load('./navbar.html');
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <h1>Please enable Javascript!</h1>
        </noscript>

        <div id="container">
                <!-- Content Here -->
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**navbar.html**

```
<div id="navbar">
        <li><object width="64" height="64" data="favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></li>
        <li><object width="64" height="64" data="icons/tech.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></li>
        <li><object width="64" height="64" data="icons/games.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></li>
        <li><object width="64" height="64" data="icons/contact.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></li>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do here, is have many HTML pages which all *link* to one navbar html page, so when I change the navbar.html, I dont have to change every page.

I already have another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371798/html-persistance-navbar). [Davor Milnaric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338290/davor-mlinaric) suggested "if you are using jquery, you can try with '.load()' function. api.jquery.com/load" but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Use $(document).ready() - read [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/); All jQuery code must be wrapped like this:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       //jquery code goes here....        

   });
   ```
2. Change

   `$('#navbar').load('./navbar.html');`

to

```
$('#container').load('./navbar.html');
```

.. you don't have an element with id="navbar"
and according to [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> If no element is matched by the selector — in this case, if the document does not contain an element with id="result" (*in our case "navbar"*) — the Ajax request will not be sent.

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible that you need to wait for the DOM to load.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#result').load('navbar.html #navbar', function() {
                alert("loaded");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="result">
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you're reply. :) When I try this, nothing changes, the navbar still doesn't load... Any ideas?

Comment: if you open `dev tools` for the browser, you will see the error, it could be  'Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data...'