# Javascript - load template in html of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

I have a template that I want to render inside html element on click of element. I want to do something like ( I am using jquery):

```
$(".btn")on("click", function(){ 
     $("#element").html(partial_template.html)
});
```

Buto this of course wont work. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I am using Django, if this matters!

Comment: You want to take a look at Ajax/API Calls.

Comment: You can either do it with AJAX or with a library like Handlebars which lets you define your HTML in a template that is then properly injected as a partial. I would recommend using handlebars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.load to load HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755426/jquery-load-to-load-html-file)

Answer (score 1):

Use .load() function , make sur to set the right path to your html tpl .

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(){ 
     $("#element").load("path_to_your_html_folder/partial_template.html");
});
```