# Unable to load html file through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

`list.html` is not loading. Is this the correct way to load html file?

```
<div id="subscription"> </div>
<script>
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.getElementById("subscription").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="list.html"></object>'
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you have 5 items in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use:

```
<object type="text/html" data="list.html" ></object>
```

Best advice could be using `<iframe>`s:

```
<div id="subscription"> </div>
<script>
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  document.getElementById("subscription").innerHTML = '<iframe src="list.html"></iframe>';
}
</script>
```

But not sure why you need to loop it 5 times. You can just do:

```
<div id="subscription"> </div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("subscription").innerHTML = '<iframe src="list.html"></iframe>';
</script>
```

Comment: Iist.html contains certain code that i need to loop

Comment: @vivekkumarchoubey Then you are doing it ultimately wrong. Can you explain in your question, what you are trying to do exactly? This looks like an XY problem - you are trying to do something, but you are doing it incorrectly assuming some wrong way to do and asking help for it.

Comment: @vivekkumarchoubey You can, but you need to use AJAX and also you need to run it on a HTTP server, and not using `file:///` protocol.

Comment: I want to make dynamic web page where count can increase and decrease depending on number of users. Here i am using constant 5 just for example .

Comment: @vivekkumarchoubey In that case, you need to use a `localhost` using some HTTP server. Do you have any experience in backend programming - PHP seems to be a best start. What you are doing is called "including partials". `:)`

Comment: I am using Apache server

Comment: @vivekkumarchoubey Is PHP enabled in your server?

Comment: @vivekkumarchoubey You can try using jQuery and AJAX. Are you okay with that? Please try checking this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16755426